# Qual a diferença entre marginStart/marginLeft e marginEnd/marginRight?

Tags: android, xml

Sei que essa dúvida é bastante simples, mas já procurei e ainda não achei uma resposta que me fosse satisfatória. Afinal de contas o `marginLeft` não é equivalente ao `marginStart`? E também não seria a mesma coisa para o `marginEnd` e o `marginRight`? Será que alguém poderia me explicar a diferença entre essas propriedades `XML` do android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A grande diferença entre elas só é percebida em aparelhos usando alguma linguagem que exige a leitura RTL (Right to Left) e não LTR (Left to Right) como estamos acostumados.

É possível forçar essa visão usando as configurações de desenvolvedor, mas não é muito comum utilizarmos isso.

O suporte pra RTL só apareceu completamente no Android 4.2, mas já tinha um suporte básico no Android 4.1, esse [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) pode ajudar a entender.

---

Voltando a pergunta, o `marginStart` e `marginEnd`, assim como o `paddingStart` e `paddingEnd` vão gerar o mesmo resultado se o aparelho estiver em LTR que seus atributos fixos: `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, `paddingLeft` e `paddingRight` respectivamente, mas se o aparelho estiver em RTL vai ser exatamente o oposto.

Quando você usa `marginLeft`, está aplicando a margem a esquerda (fixa) do elemento na visão LTR. Se usar `marginStart`, essa margem se aplica ao início (relativa). No caso da visão LTR é a esquerda do elemento, mas no caso do RLT é a direita do elemento.

Minha sugestão é sempre usar os atributos relativos caso seu `minSdkVersion` for maior que 17 (Android 4.2). Se seu `minSdkVersion` é menor que 17, use sempre os dois em conjunto com os mesmos valores. e.g: `marginLeft` e `marginStart`.